# Shipping methods are not displayed accordingly in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, sorting, shipping-methods

How can I display the list of my shipping methods according to the order numbers that I have set in their input fields of **Sort Order**?

I have set each shipping method's **Sort Order** in my backoffice, but they are not displayed accordingly.

For instance, in my backoffice, I have these shipping methods,

```
Method Name: bestway
Sort Order: 1

Method Name: Free
Sort Order: 2

Method Name: Chronopost
Sort Order: 3
```

But they are not displayed in this order in `frontend\argenties\default\template\checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

```
    <?php
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    $shipping = array();
    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier):
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods()):
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                $_title = $_ccode;

            foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method):
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $shipping[$_code] = array('title' => $_method,'carrier' => $_title);
            ?>

            <li><input type="radio" name="estimate_method" value="<?php echo $_code;?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"<?php if($_code === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>> <span class="item-text-shipping-method"><?php echo $_title;?></span></li>

            <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Result,

```
Method Name: Free
Method Name: bestway
Method Name: Chronopost
```

`Method Name: bestway` should be on the top in the list, but it is always dropped to the second. Why? Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `getActiveCarriers()` is not sorting shipping methods.

So what you can do is first to fetch shipping methods into array getting sort order with the following bit of code:

```
$sort_order = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/$_code/sort_order');
```

And then sort your carriers by it.

This is how sorting during the checkout is working (@see Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm still stuck. Where can I pass `$sort_order` into the code in my question?

Comment: Well, this is a basic PHP question to just make an array of objects and then sort it by one or properties.